# Highcharts - Series tooltip doesn't work when plotting lines that zigzag on the x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, highcharts

I have a highcharts chart that I need to plot but which has lines which can go back on themselves on the X Axis.
e.g. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kgoodman/V92NB/3/)

My problem isn't that I can't plot it but rather the series tooltips don't display correctly.
If you zoom right in to individual points they seem ok, but not at normal zoom level.
E.g. if you scan your mouse across the series from right to left it doesn't want to show you the tooltip on x Value 1, intead it jumps to the second set of values on x value 2.

I've changed the tooltips to being not shared:

```
        tooltip: {
        shared: false,
    },
```

but this has made little difference, apart from now it seems to work when zoomed in, but I suspect this is only because there are only one set of x Axis values visible.

Does anybody know how it is possible to configure Highcharts to allow for series where the x values aren't sorted either ascending or descending as I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data):

> Note that line series and derived types like spline and area, require
>   data to be sorted by X because it interpolates mouse coordinates for
>   the tooltip. Column and scatter series, where each point has its own
>   mouse event, does not require sorting.

So change your series to `type: 'scatter'` with a `lineWidth` > 0.  Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V92NB/4/).

Comment: Perfect answer. Many thanks for your help. I had read that but it was very late and it just didn't twig that's what it meant.